# Создание события на новый элемент в админ панеле WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Необходимо создать пользовательскую кнопку в админке поста. Кнопку разобрался как создать и вывести в админке. Каким образом теперь на нее добавить хук, что бы при клике происходила отправка письма?

Comment: Надо вешать на нее ajax: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: Догадывался, но думал для админки как то по другому работает это все. А тогда вопрос в следующем, в каком файле будет это правильно прописать ajax, тоесть js код?

Comment: Ну уж не в файлах ядра! Читайте материал по ссылке, там все изложено. Запускайте в теме `admin_enqueue_scripts()`, там указывайте ваш js. Опять же в теме создавайте хук для ответа на ajax.